# Why does Laravel generate a new session on every request?

Tags: laravel

I'm working on a client project, and I finished everything and today I wanted to test if everything works okay. However I noticed that Laravel generates a new session every time I refresh the page. Keep in mind this didn't happen ever before, just today when I wanted to test.

Comment: Usually this is the result of the session cookie not sticking. Have you disabled cookies? Is it trying to assign a cookie with the wrong domain? The "Network" inspector can usually help diagnose.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your SESSION_DRIVER is not null and COOKIE_DOMAIN has no port number. Sometimes this gives issue.

Comment: I don't have COOKIE_DOMAIN in my session.php file nor the .env file, could that be a problem? If yes what's the correct syntax to insert it ?

Comment: If not in COOKIE_DOMAIN then check in this directory config/session.php

Comment: In this file if there is any COOKIE_DOMAIN then replace it the domain you want to store your cookie in or leave it null.